# How to verify if the password reset token exists in table and display a message if not

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Got laravel's password reset setuped correctly and working, now whats left is how to verify if the reset token exists in the password_resets table and proceed if valid. At the moment if I type in my url example.com/password/reset/somestuff it redirects me to the page where it asks for email and password, so there's no security :)
Thanks and I hope you understood my question.

Comment: `example.com/password/reset/somestuff` would take you to the the from but if you tried to submit it, the `This password reset token is invalid.` error will be shown. So what is the security issue?

Comment: if you want to manually check if the token is exist in the `password_resets` table, then you can override the `showResetForm()` in the `ResetPasswordController`. [`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Password` trait's method.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the laravel query builder to make this check. For example:

```
if(DB::table('table_name')
    ->where('user', $user)
    ->whereNotNull('token')
    ->exists()){
    do something
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries